# mqtt exception Too many publishes in progress (32202)

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am using paho mqttv3 java client for publishing messages  concurrently around 2000 connections by creating threads.

After some time it starts giving MqttException is folows :

```
reason----- 32202
msg--------Too many publishes in progress
cause------ null
```

Although I have set Qos 1.

Anyone knows why I am getting such exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the Paho synchronous or asynchronous client?

Comment: I am also getting the error. Using async client with qos 2.

Comment: I get this error regardless of MqttClient or MqttAsyncClient

Comment: I'm getting this error too. In my case the problem is the client.

Answer (score 10):

I just came across another question which answer helped me out with this problem.

You have to set an higher MaxInflight value by using `setMaxInflight()` method from the `MqttConnectOptions` object before connecting to the broker.

The default value is set to 10.

The original topic is : [Send many publish message: Too many publishes in progress Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751546/send-many-publish-message-too-many-publishes-in-progress-error)

Comment: I have this problem as well now. Increasing maxInflight in successive steps up to 10_000 didn't help: "Too many publishes in progress" continues to happen. Our MQTT topic is receiving messages forwarded from a RabbitMQ queue. Any suggestions what to do greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a limit on the server or client side.

If it is a server limit, you should look at the specific documentation on how to tune it up to handle more clients.

If it is a client limit, then instead of `MqttClient` try out the `MqttAsyncClient` (non-blocking) Java client.

You can start looking at the three different examples [here](https://github.com/jacyzon/paho.mqtt.java/tree/master/org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/sample/mqttv3app)

**Sample** which uses the API which blocks until the operation completes

**SampleAsyncWait** shows how to use the asynchronous API with waiters that block until an action completes

**SampleAsyncCallBack** shows how to use the asynchronous API where events are used to notify the application when an action completes

Comment: The link to the repository is broken.

Comment: Correct link [here](https://github.com/jacyzon/paho.mqtt.java/tree/master/org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/sample/mqttv3app)

Comment: downvoting because this happens when using the async client