# Send many publish message: Too many publishes in progress Error

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, paho

Here is paho Async client:

```
    client = new MqttAsyncClient(appProps.getProperty("mqtt.broker"),
            appProps.getProperty("mqtt.clientId"), new MemoryPersistence());
    client.setCallback(this);
    client.connect(null, new IMqttActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken imt) {
            try {
                client.subscribe(Constants.internalTopics, Constants.internalTopicQOS);
            } catch (MqttException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(IMqttToken imt, Throwable thrwbl) {
            thrwbl.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Here I am sending messages in loop:

```
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            try {
               client.publish("user/" + userId + "/downstream", mqttMessage);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
Too many publishes in progress (32202)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.send(ClientState.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.internalSend(ClientComms.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.publish(MqttAsyncClient.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.publish(MqttAsyncClient.java:836)
```

I am using `Rabbitmq`

Comment: Some context would be really useful here, like how many messages are in the queue?  How far through the list are you when the error arrives?

Comment: I had a list of 1000 that i am iterating. I found that after reaching to 200-300 its start throwing error. One more thing at that time there was no subscriber to all those 1000 topic. So just a publisher no subscriber

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttConnectOptions.java#L44) for the Paho client it looks like the default maximum number of inflight messages at any given time is 10.

So given how tight your publish loop is it will only take a small slow down in the network layer and your going to end up with more than 10 messages in the process of being sent at any given time. This will only get worse if you try to send at a QOS greater than 0.

You can change the default with the `setMaxInflight(int n)` method on the `MQTTConnectionsOptions` object that is passed to the `client.connect()` method.

I suggest you experiment to find a suitable value.

Comment: In web application  this is common scanerio that you are getting 1000 message from your web users and it has to be delivered. So how those siuations are handled ?

Comment: Set a suitable value for the limit

Comment: Also you shouldn't really be publishing the same message to 1000s of different topics, publish it to 1 topic and have the 1000s of subscribers.

Comment: How will you design a scenario. Imagine you have 1M post,  every time a comment is added to a post all other user who commented on that particular post should be notified. What I am doing is that i iterate through all user id and sending message to `user/<user_id>` topic

Comment: A topic per story, when a user comments they subscribe to the story topic

Comment: are you sure ?? cos one user can make comment to 100's post so that mean subscribe to 100's topic and it will keep growing. and also if there 1M post there will be 1M topic just for post

Comment: So what is your take on this. Dont you think there will topic subscription limit on js client ?