# mosquitto mqtt got too many publishes in progress error

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

We use mosquitto in our project to connect our IoT devices to cloud.

However, we always got "too many publishes in progress" error when there are only 30 devices(The server has 3.1 CPU and 8G RAM).

We tried setting the qos to 0,1,2. However, none worked.

Can anyone give some advices how to fix it?

publishmesssage

```
public static void publishMessage(MqttPubMsg config) {
    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

    MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(config.getBroker(), clientId, persistence);
    MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
    connOpts.setUserName(config.getUsername());
    connOpts.setPassword(config.getPassword().toCharArray());
    connOpts.setConnectionTimeout(mqttConnectTimeout);
    connOpts.setKeepAliveInterval(mqttKeppAliveInterval);

    sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(config.getContent());
    message.setQos(0);
    sampleClient.publish(config.getTopic(), message);
    System.out.println("Message published");
}
```

mosquitto.conf

```
max_inflight_messages 0
max_queued_messages   0
max_connections -1
```

subscribemessage

```
public static void subscribeMessage(MqttSubMsg config) {
    System.out.println(config.getBroker());
    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();

    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

    MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(config.getBroker(), clientId, persistence);
    MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
    connOpts.setUserName(config.getUsername());
    connOpts.setPassword(config.getPassword().toCharArray());
    connOpts.setConnectionTimeout(mqttConnectTimeout);
    connOpts.setKeepAliveInterval(mqttKeppAliveInterval);

    System.out.println("run receive...");
    sampleClient.setCallback(new controllers.PushCallback());
    MqttTopic mtopic = sampleClient.getTopic(config.getTopic());
    connOpts.setWill(mtopic, "close".getBytes(), 0, true);
    sampleClient.connect(connOpts);

    int[] Qos = {0};
    String[] topic1 = {config.getTopic()};
    sampleClient.subscribe(topic1, Qos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me show, how to solve such problems yourself -

Open the Github web page for Paho client and search for the "too many publishes in progress":

[image: browser screenshot]

This leads you to the "32202" string, search for it again.

This leads you (after skipping few localization files) to the constant in the Java source code file [MqttException.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttException.java):

```
public static final short REASON_CODE_MAX_INFLIGHT = 32202;
```

And again, search for the "REASON_CODE_MAX_INFLIGHT" - which finally brings you to the file [ClientState.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/ClientState.java):

```
    if (actualInFlight >= this.maxInflight) {
        //@TRACE 613= sending {0} msgs at max inflight window
        log.fine(CLASS_NAME, methodName, "613", new Object[]{new Integer(actualInFlight)});

        throw new MqttException(MqttException.REASON_CODE_MAX_INFLIGHT);
    }
```

So you need to adjust the `maxInflight` property.

Few more searches and you find out that it can be set by calling the `setMaxInflight(int maxInflight)` method on an [MqttConnectionOptions](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttConnectOptions.html) object that you pass to the `connect` method of a Paho client.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with mosquitto, it is the client you are using. See this answer: [Send many publish message: Too many publishes in progress Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751546/send-many-publish-message-too-many-publishes-in-progress-error)

Comment: our client of the IoT devices directly use JAVA to call APIs to communicate with mosquitto. We don't use any third party clients.

Comment: I meant the client library you are using. You are using a third party client library which is the Paho Java client library. The answer that I've linked to explains how to use the Paho Java API to expand the number of messages it will process at once.